# Mongo command line eval exits without error

Tags: bash, mongodb

I can't seem to .remove() from the command line. My query works fine if I go into the mongo shell, but not directly from bash.

```
$ mongo mydatabase --eval 'db.mytable.remove({expires: {$lt: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)}})'
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: mydatabase
```

This command takes hours to run on all of our data when run manually through the mongo shell. It returns instantly without error from the bash shell like above.

I know there's data and can confirm it with a similar `--eval`:

```
$ mongo mydatabase --eval 'printjson(db.mytable.findOne({expires: {$lt: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)}}))'
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: mydatabase 
{
        "_id" : "39e493ccef9d58bf75d856f55fb269f6",
        "value" : "mydata",
        "expires" : NumberLong(1371486135)
}
```

Any ideas why the `db.mytable.remove()` fails without error?

Comment: If it takes a long time to run, make sure you have a descending index on the expires field! If you run the query as a find() rather than a remove, does it find any records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried now with MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2 and it works fine:

```
mongo test --eval 'db.things.remove({expires: {$lt: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)}})'
```

Try to update MongoDB to a newer version if you are not already updated, plus [I heard](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#javascript-engine-changed-to-v8) that latests mongoDB version use V8 Javascript engine could be useful

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that in the shell, `remove` is not using getLastError, and is therefore asynchronous. If you fire off the command, you can check `db.currentOp()` to see if there are any commands running.

It's also possible that your query as given is being interpreted in the shell in such a way that it's not matching any records to delete. Make sure that a `find` returns data using that same query.

It's *also* possible that 2.0.6's shell uses the second `justOne` parameter by default, making it find and delete the first matching record, at which point it'll return. You might try passing an explicit second parameter `false` to force it to multi-record mode. I don't have a 2.0.6 shell to test with, but it's something to check for.